# Storing multiple images with multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to create a question system that allow the users to create a dynamic amount of question with also a dynamic amount of answer (they can choose from simple text based, to image based answer). Having the following collection of image files in the request:

```
'image_opt' =>array:4 [▼
          0 => array:1 [▼
              0 => "file_q1_1"
              1 => "file_q1_2"
          ]
          1 => array:1 [▼
              0 => "file_q2_1"
              1 => "file_q2_2"
          ]
          2 => array:4 [▼
              0 => "file_q3_1"
              1 => "file_q3_2"
              2 => "file_q3_3"
              3 => "file_q3_4"
          ]
      ]
```

How could I fetch each file and store it in the server? So far I've tried this

```
$answer = new Answer();

$file = $request->image_opt[$i][$j];
$name = str_random(45) . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$folder = '/uploads/answers/';

$path = $file->storeAs($folder, $name, 'public');
$answer->answer = $folder . $name;
$answer->question_id = $question->id;
$answer->max_weight = 0;
$answer->weight = $request->image_weight[$i][$j];
$answer->answer_type_id = $question->question_type_id;
$answer->save();
```

Problem is...I can't fetch the file, I only have the string at that point according to the error.

```
Call to a member function storeAs() on string
```

Also tried which didn't work either.

```
$file = $request->file(image_opt[$i][$j]);
```

How can I get each file from the collection? $i would represent the current question being stored and $j the answer that's being storede and img_opt is the collection of files.

EDIT:

HTML form:

```
<div id="image_0" style="display:none;">
    <div id="clone_image_container_0" >
        <div id="clone_image_me_0" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >Respuesta</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control clonable-increment-name"  name="image_opt[0][]" >
                </div>
            </div>                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 layer-2-html" >Peso</label>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control clonable-increment-name" name="image_weight[0][]" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ></label>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs clonable-increment-onClick" onClick="CloneFrm(0,'image');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's a cloner that clone a "question form" and another that clone an "option form". Whenever a question form gets cloned, the name from the input file increase by one like 'img_opt[1][]'

In the case of an image, if there's 2 questions with 2 images each and log the request I would get

```
img_opt[0][0] = file_q1_1
img_opt[0][1] = file_q1_2
img_opt[1][0] = file_q2_1
img_opt[1][1] = file_q2_2
```

Comment: `$request->file(image_opt[$i][$j]);` looks incorrect; it would be `$request->file("image_opt")[$i][$j];`, although I'm not sure where you're getting `image_opt`; maybe include your form/post data?

Comment: But doing `$request->file("image_opt")` how can I specify, for example, that he should get file "file_q3_2"?

Comment: Maybe that would be `$request->file("image_opt.2.1")`? Or, you could loop `$request->file("image_opt")`, like `foreach($request->file("image_opt") AS $image){ ... }`

Comment: Just tried `$request->file("image_opt.2.1")`, it did not work. Wouldn't `foreach($request->file("image_opt") AS $image){ ... }` fail because file("image_opt") would be trying to read an array of arrays?

Comment: Hmm, yeah. And no, it wouldn't fail per-say, it just means that `$image` would be an array, so you'd need to do another `foreach` (nested looping)

Comment: Sorry I can't get the nested looping to work, after the first `foreach($request->file("image_opt") AS $image)` the next foreach would be `foreach($image->file($i) as $specific_image)` $i being the number of the subarray?

Comment: Not quite. `foreach($request->file("image_opt") AS $images){ foreach($images AS $image){ ... } }`. Not sure where you got `$image->file($i)` from.

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` on the first call

Comment: You'll probably have to include your form or ajax request; I'm not sure how you're sending these files, you might have an issue there.

Comment: Edited some of the form, specifically the image type answer form. Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: Hmm, everything looks correct in that regard. Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` element? (required when uploading images in Laravel).

Comment: Oh wow...it was the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` jeez...I can't believe it /facepalm. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yup! Can do. And that actually explains a lot of the issues now that I think of it. 1 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `<form>` element has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to properly handle image uploads in Laravel. Omitting this can cause issues, and obviously is in this situation.

```
<form method="POST" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This error:

> Call to a member function storeAs() on string

Is due to how `$request->image_opt[$i][$j]` is defaulting to a `string` value for uploaded images. This would be equivalent to calling `$request->input("image_opt")[$i][$j]`, but this isn't an `input()` variable, it's a `file()` variable.

Next error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

For the same reason, `foreach($request->file("image_opt) AS $images){ ... }` is returning `null` when `enctype` is omitted. It *should* be an array, and would be if you used `$request->input()`, but that's also an error.

TL:DR; don't forget `enctype`; omitting it was the cause of the various issues encountered.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience.